# JQuery Datable PDF/Excel Export not working with server side processing

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with datatable export functionality, When I use below code

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "oTableTools": {
        "aButtons": [
            "copy",
            "csv",
            {
                "sExtends": "xls",
                "sxlsMessage": "Excel title"
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "pdf",
                "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                "sPdfMessage": "Pdf Title",
                "sPdfTitle": document.title
            },
            "print"
        ]
    }
```

this works fine for me but binding data with server side processing true, My table loads it all data, pagination, sorting and all functionality are working but export functionality not working, actually export button are also not displaying and it also is not loaded in DOM.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,      
    "oTableTools": {
        "aButtons": [
            "copy",
            "csv",
            {
                "sExtends": "xls",
                "sxlsMessage": "Excel title"
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "pdf",
                "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                "sPdfMessage": "Pdf title",
                "sPdfTitle": document.title
            },
            "print"
        ]
    },
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "ServerData/AjaxPage.aspx",
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "STATUS" },
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the tabletools script and css?
You have also to initialize the table with the proper options
"sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/